# Problem with Geometry Dash user-search

Tags: geometry-dash

this is my first question in gaming Stack Exchange. I want to ask, why do my Username stats shows me like "resetted". The stars value was 0, diamond 0, demons 0, etc. But if I clicked the username to shows more detail about my account, it's ok.. no problem with those values. The same problem also happened to my friend.

Here are some shots:

My Account:
[image: PuteraEuclidian Search Result]
[image: PuteraEuclidian Account Info]
[image: Friend results]
[image: Friend info]

But my old account result was fine
[image: Old account result]
[image: Old account info]

That's all I want to ask in this thread right now. I'll keep asking if I got problems

INFO: I'm Indonesian, sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

This happens to everyones profile, it's because the leaderboards haven't been resetted in a long time, for example, if go to the top 100 and click on any of their profiles, they will have better stats than shown.
Or if you go to your own profile and check your place on the leaderboard it shows something different to when you go to the global leaderboard and check your place there.

It's not really a bug, or a problem, just a small annoyance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you play Geometry Dash on multiple devices? If so, that might be the reason because, with multiple profiles (for each device), Geometry Dash might glitch and return to default for your public profile (all stats are zero). However when you click on the profile, then it shows your private profile (The stats you have on the device) only if you click on your own name. For any other person, if they visit your profile, the stats will show 0 to them. Fix this by logging out on all devices you play on except one.</strike>

It turns out that my solution is not correct. Have you saved yet? If you haven't saved, then your public profile might show 0 stars, 0 demons, etcetera because your public profile has the same stats as the stats you had when you last saved (if you haven't saved, your stats will show as 0). To fix this save.